# Only wrap text at edge of div, not anywhere else

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html-lists, word-break

I currently have an ordered list like this one where the numbers and items are centered and left aligned:

[image]

I achieved this using this css:

```
ol
{
padding-left:1em;
padding-right:1em;
display: inline-block;
text-align: left;

word-break: break-word !important;
/*white-space: nowrap*/

}
```

The problem I am seeing is that it wraps text strangely - it will wrap list items (create a new line) if they are a certain amount longer than the other list items. This creates things like in the picture above (or in text format):

1.Sleeping
  Bags
2.Tent
3.Food
4.Stove
5.Jackets
6.Bug Spray

Notice how the Bags is on a new line, but that is not where the div ends.  I tried using `white-space: nowrap`, but obviously that does what it says and long text then continues beyond the `div` without breaking.

Also, it may just be some sort of browser glitch because sometimes when I hit back and the page is cached it will load correctly, and in safari instead of chrome it *seems* to work correctly without `white-space: nowrap`.

Any help / ideas appreciated, or if it is just some weird unfixable thing, I am sorry

Comment: where is your `html`

Answer (score 1):

You can try Below code:

[working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/08ay81b1/)

```
div{text-align:center;}
ol
  {
   padding-left:1em;
   padding-right:1em;
   display: inline-block;
   text-align: left;
   word-break: break-word !important;
   /*white-space: nowrap*/

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the list a (bigger) width:

```
ol {
  width: 200px;
  ... rest of CSS
}
```

As for debugging, I often add a `border: 1px solid red;` so you can see how far the element extends. If you add it to the `ol` you'll see that it's width causes the line break. So making it bigger should do the trick.